# Search the internet for pictures by keyword and automatically download a set number of the results in the original resolutions (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: images, ubuntu, download-manager, search, internet

This is the task I would like to be able to perform:

1. Search for images on the internet by a keyword
2. Automatically download a specified number of the search results in the original image resolutions as found on the sites where the images are hosted.

My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04.

I used to be able to accomplish this by searching on googleimageripper.com then downloading the results using DownThemAll for firefox, but googleimageripper is now a subscription site.

I would be willing to pay for commercial software that could do this but I don't want to subscribe to pay sites.

Thanks.